# create a Java application, which will use an ec2 role to access the restricted s3 bucket on Local

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

```
  AmazonS3 s3;
  s3  = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).build();
  return s3;
```

I am creating s3 client without providing any credentials now If I use any api using this s3 client it will throw an saying access denied .

```
  AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, accessSecret);
  return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withRegion(region).build();
```

With using this code it will work but I dont want to provide accessKey and accessSecret.
I have created a role with s3bucket full access and ec2 full access . Now how to create a Java application, which will use an ec2 role to access the  restricted s3 bucket on Localwithout access key and secret key

Comment: The first snippet will work out of the box on an EC2 machine because the credentials provider chain includes one provider for ec2 credentials. On local you should run the code either with explicit credentials set or with a AWS_PROFILE set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the BasicAwsCredentials provider use the [com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) to get the credentials instance. The DefaultAWSCredentialsProvider goes in the below order.

AWS credentials provider chain that looks for credentials in this order:

- Environment Variables - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY (RECOMMENDED since they are recognized by all the AWS SDKs and CLI except for .NET), or AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY (only recognized by Java SDK)
- Java System Properties - aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey
- Web Identity Token credentials from the environment or container
- Credential profiles file at the default location (~/.aws/credentials) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI
- Credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 container service if AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" environment variable is set and security manager has permission to access the variable,
- Instance profile credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service